# R: apply one factor's levels to another object?

Tags: r

I have an object that I want to convert to a factor with the same characteristics as another existing factor.

I got some insight on how to do so at the question linked below, but it reorders the factor's levels. Another method I came up with seems to work.

Is the method I came up with brittle, or will it work in all cases? Other ideas?

```
data(chickwts)

# unfactor the feed variable
test <- c(NA, chickwts$feed)

# method 1
# from question at link below: with(chickwts,data.frame(code=as.numeric(unique(feed)),level=unique(feed)))

test.factor.close <- factor(test[2:length(test)], levels=as.numeric(unique(chickwts$feed)), labels=unique(chickwts$feed))

unique(chickwts$feed == test.factor.close) # TRUE
all.equal(chickwts$feed, test.factor.close) # "Attributes: < Component “levels”: 6 string mismatches >"

# method 2

test.factor.alleq <- factor(test[2:length(test)], levels=as.numeric(sort(unique(chickwts$feed))), labels=levels(chickwts$feed))

all.equal(chickwts$feed, test.factor.alleq) # TRUE
```

--Other question on factor levels--

[R: Mapping table of levels and labels of factor variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818330/r-mapping-table-of-levels-and-labels-of-factor-variable)

Comment: Does this work for you? `attributes(test) <- attributes(chickwts$feed)`

Comment: D'oh! That's a much simpler solution - want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@rawr pointed out in a comment that R provides a simple and transparent way to apply one object's attributes to another object. For factors, the attributes include the factor levels/labels.

```
attributes(test) <- attributes(chickwts$feed)
```